# Angular Kendo Grid Column Date Format

Tags: angular, typescript, date, kendo-grid

I have a [kendo grid column](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-format) like so:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="EntryDate" title="Date" filter="date" [format]="{ date: 'long' }"></kendo-grid-column>
```

The data looks like so:

```
"EntryDate":"2018-05-01T00:00:00-05:00"
```

The grid shows the date unformatted.  How can I get the date to show formatted correctly in the grid?

Comment: please refer this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6xzee?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I finally found my solution [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/troubleshooting/#toc-dates-are-not-properly-formatted-during-sorting-filtering-or-editing-dates-are-treated-as-strings).  I had to map the response again `data: response['value'].map(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid data needs to contain actual JavaScript Date objects as opposed to some string representations. Then built-in formatting, sorting, filtering and editing will treat the dates as such and will work as expected:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/)

Map the data so that it contains actual dates.

EXAMPLES:

[String](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ks52q?file=app/app.component.ts)

[Date](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6xzee?file=app/app.component.ts)